# Is there an easy way to protect all endpoints?

Tags: sveltekit

I have loads of endpoints to protect in my SvelteKit app. I dont' want to add following in all of them:

```js
    if (!request.locals.user) {
        return { status: 401 };
    };
```

Can I do this from `hooks.js` or in another easy and safe way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no way to add hook per endpoint in sveltekit and implementing it in the global hooks.js will be difficult because you will have to maintain protected routes path every time you change it.

The only way to do it as you said is to add the auth check in every route which is also will be difficult to maintain. to avoid that we can extract the auth check logic into its own function. the function will accept the handler that holds the route hooks:

```js
// compose one handler function out of number of handlers.
// it will execute handlers in sequence until one returned a value
function withHandlers(...handlers) {
    return async (request) => {
        for (const handle of handlers) {
            const result = await handle(request)
            if (result !== undefined) {
                return result
            }
        }
    }
}

// implementation of auth check
function authHook(request) {
    if (!request.locals.user) {
        return {
            status: 401,
            body: {
                message: 'unauthorized'
            }
        };
    }
}

// create a new handler with auth check
function withAuth(handle) {
    return withHandlers(authHook, handle);
}

// your final endpoint with authentication check
export const get = withAuth((request) => {
    return {
        body: `Hello ${request.locals.user}`
    };
});
```

Comment: I had to tidy up a bit but now I am ready to try out your answer...I am a bit dumb...would you mind to split your code example with an example for each file `hooks.js`, `index.js`?